# Trouble importing (es6) firebase 3 npm module into angular

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ecmascript-6

For some reason, the Angular is saying that it cannot find the firebase module? No problem importing other module in the same fashion.

```
import angular from 'angular';

// angular modules
import constants from './constants';
import onConfig  from './on_config';
import onRun     from './on_run';
import 'angular-ui-router';
import 'firebase/app'
import './templates';
import './filters';
import './controllers';
import './services';
import './directives';

// create and bootstrap application
const requires = [
  'firebase',  
  'ui.router',
  'templates',
  'app.filters',
  'app.controllers',
  'app.services',
  'app.directives'
];

window.app = angular.module('app', requires);
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem, or have any suggestion where I might be going wrong?

I'm importing this file which I believe should load the correct library

```
/**
 *  Firebase app for browser npm package.
 *
 * Usage:
 *
 *   firebase = require('firebase/app');
 */
require('./firebase-app');
module.exports = firebase;
```

Here is the classic error

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module firebase due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'firebase' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can import the whole module with:

```
   import * as firebase from 'firebase'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused: the es6 module path needs to end in .js and begin with a relative or global path, i.e. ./ or ../ or http://path/to/dir/

Possibly there is preprocessing of some sort that "legalizes" the OP's paths? Or is this just Angular's import?

If real es6 modules, the changes suggested will work on browsers supporting modules.